# integrate KDIFF in explorer context menu

Tags: windows-server-2008, context-menu

I'm using windows server 2008 and I have KDIFF installed on it.

On previous computers I worked with I was able to R+Click a file and perform KDIFF related actions.

But now I don't have this option and i can't find any thing in it's preferences to activate it.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someone told me that on the download page at source forge there was the light version instead of the full version.

so I un-installed the old version and downloaded a new one today and installed it.

Now every thing works

Comment: Hi Noa, Welcome to Super User! would you mind editing your answer and adding a source link as a reference?